# Adobe CQ - Create content package with XPath query

Tags: adobe, aem

In the Adobe CQ 5.3 Package Manager I want to create a package for pages with a certain sling:resourceType ("foundation/components/text"). So I tried to add a XPath query to the "Filters" dialogue as seen in the following screenshot, but it didn't work.

[image: Screenshot with dialogue]

With which query can I create the package for the pages with the `sling:resourceType="foundation/components/text"`?

Comment: I don't think the include / exclude accepts an XPath Query, rather it accepts a regex input. Kindly confirm it once.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer. Do you know how I can do it with a regex command?

Comment: Through regex, I am not sure if you can include the path for the pages containing text nodes. However, you may be able to include the path for the individual text nodes.